# git actions are asking me for username / password on some directories and not for others

Tags: macos, git, github

I have an SSH key setup for git (using github) that works great.
However - I recently started working on a certain directory (with a few git repositories under it) and on those repositories - each action I do - requires me to use a username and password.

Any other directory - everything works well.

I would add that the repositories there used to work on `svn` and now we're using `git` with them (in case it has any relevance). I did however try re-cloning and removing all `svn` files - makes no difference.

Another thing I noticed - is the submodules also require username and password, but a submodule of the submodule works without them.

I'm really lost on it and it's really annoying - would appriciate help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well , After looking into it - I realised that it was not a matter of directory - but new and old repositories.

It seemed like it just broke at some point. (Perhaps upgrading to Mountain lion , perhaps installing new git myself outside of Xcode)

I decided to go to our good friends at github (with their great FAQ).
I just re-did the following setting up tutorial and it now works like a charm:
https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git

Hopefully this helps someone in the future with the same annoying issue.

Liviu

Answer (score 0):

Each submodules are Git repo on their own, with their own remote GitHub 'origin'.
If your ssh key isn't added to *those* repo, GitHub will ask for username/password for push operations.

Comment: As I mentioned:
A. I use many git repositories with that account - successfully , (On which I am an admin) All of them using the same submodule (Think of it as a project + sdk as submodule) B.My ssh key is configured globally - like github instructs.
C. My problem is mainly with the first - non-submoduled repository (base project) and the first tier of submodule repositories. The exact same configuration works on other projects outside that directory. Thanks :)